# How to customize push notifications in Bluemix

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to configure NodeRED to send notifications to the Android apps on devices of a specific user and people who are registered as his family in the logic. I have never dealt with push notifications and I don't know what to look for so steps or even keywords to look up is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Generally you can now see flows of your notification service. In the Node-RED flow editor, double-click the notification node to open the Edit function node dialog box. You should edit the payload object to customize the message notification.

Here there is an example that could be useful for you http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-nodered-push-app/

Comment: My problem is not with the load that is being sent, I know how to edit that. My issue is with dynamically customizing the target devices based on the input source.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using tags to group this 'family' of users together. After creating the tag, you will need some logic on the Android side to identify if the user is part of that family. If they are, you can subscribe them to the appropriate tag, then you can send a notification to all subscribers of that tag with one REST call. See the Bluemix doc [Enabling tag-based notifications](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/c_tag_basednotifications.html) for more info.

As a general note, you can also send notifications to single users if you have their device ID. The device ID is included in the response after registering with the Push Notifications service and should be saved somewhere if you plan on using it for very specific push notifications. Something to consider, let me know if this helps.

Comment: The issue with the tag solution is that I can't group every family in a tag, because every registered user will have his own corresponding family. What I had hoped to have is something similar to database entries of a user's family members and that application can just look that up.

Comment: The issue is that I am used to relational databases so I don't know how to use cloudant to serve my purpose.

Comment: You could create tags for each person, there is not a limit. But if that is not a satisfactory solution, maybe linking deviceIds together in some fashion would help you keep the number of different tags down. At the very least, if you were able to link some of the users' deviceIds, you could recursively send the same notification to the entire trail or stack of users in that family.

Comment: Is using tags for this kind of problem considered good practice? It seems to me it may be a bad design practice. I'll look into both methods though, thank you very much!

Comment: Tags are great for grouping users together for group specific notifications. This fits your use case well and is not a bad practice. However, I suggest remembering basics about push notifications. They are never guaranteed and should never send critical or sensitive data, this is part of the native design.